# How can I accept license agreement while running jar file through Python

Tags: python, jar, aws-glue

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['java','-jar','file.jar','*req_params_for_jar*'])
```

I am running this in a python shell using AWS glue. While running the jar file, it prints the accept license agreement on the logs and keeps waiting for an interactive input Y or yes. How can I pass this in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing to stdin with [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).
Code example, modified from your original code:

```py
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', 'file.jar','req_params_for_jar'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
child.stdin.write(b"Y")
print(child.communicate()[0])
child.stdin.close()
```

Try it online (grep example) [here](https://tio.run/##XYy9CsMgFEb3PIVkUSFIoXPGDt2yJxkalSroveIPoU9vg1nSjt/hOyd8skG412p9wJhJKluIKHVKnTTWKTJekJgwaGAzfUcd6ECo0c4hXQeSsrIwXp/P6dEwlvzP@ZkWTRJ7tFmzrW@tBXaMTi3QFmmj512IFjI7LYneF7DydVh8vq2/NekwHbzWLw).

Comment: It threw an error saying TypeError: a bytes-like object required not 'str', so I passed input=b'Yes', the jobs runs and the license agreement acceptance is again printed on the console and it keeps waiting for an input.

Comment: Edited post, try it again now. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: passing input=b"Yes" also works now, I had an S3 connection on my AWS glue job which was causing the wait and preventing it from running.